# Deducing a function from its derivative.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

A function $f$ is to be found out such that its derivative $f'(x)$ is given by
 $$f'(x)= \frac{192 x^3}{2+ \sin^4\pi x} \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

The value of the function at $x=0$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I have absolutely no idea on how to integrate $f'(x)$. Is it possible to find $f(x)$ at all? How can this integral be evaluated?

Comment: I think we just need to get an approximation for sin like near 0 $sin (x)\approx x $ or get an upper or lower bound for function using $0\leq sin^4 (x)\leq 1 $ as function is highly unlikely to be integrable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a closed form expression for the integral, then I would guess that there is no such closed form in elementary functions.

But if you are simply looking for an antiderivative $f$ of $f'$ such that $f(0) = 1/2$, then the unique such function is
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \int_0^x \frac{192 t^3}{2 + \sin^4 \pi t} dt.$$
For any value of $x$, it is possible to numerically estimate $f(x)$ up to any desired accuracy.